# Visual Studio 2015 Very Slow File Opening?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, startup, slowdown

I just downloaded VS15 2015 Community on my Windows 10 machine, and just installed all of the default packages.
For whatever reason, if I try to open a javascript file, or nearly any other extension, it takes about a full 15-20 seconds for it to load. This code says nothing but the word test in text.
Now for whatever reason, if I decide to right click the javascript file and select

Open With > "Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector"
instead of with plain Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, it opens instantly, in like 2-3 seconds tops...

What is going on? This is so irritating! I've already reinstalled VS 3 times, cleaning out all old junk files, and even tried running it without a single tool or extension installed, and it still behaves this way unless I open it with Visual Studio Version Selector, which happens to not be listed in my list of default programs in the control panel, just the original Microsoft VS 15, so I can't even set it to that as a workaround.
If anyone know what could be wrong or a possible fix, please let me know! 
Thank You!

Comment: Why is this getting voted down?

Comment: I don't know why it's getting down voted, a team member has this problem. I upvoted to try to counter the downvote fairies.

Comment: I'm seeing this very same problem, so I've up voted this too. (Thanks @chadmyers)  If I find something that works for me, I'll post an answer.

Comment: thanks all, i still haven't found a solution myself yet, hopefully someone comes around

Comment: im still searching for answer , have anyone resolved this ?

Comment: nope, I still haven't, and haven't spent a lot of time looking either. Anyone I've met either doesn't have the issue or has never fixed it.

Comment: Upgrade to VS 2017. It seems to be faster at opening projects.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old post but I had the same problem and was looking everywhere for a solution.

What worked for me and the rest of my team was to delete the contents of the '_references.js' file that's in the 'Scripts' folder in the project. It has something to do with intellisense which doesn't seem to work anyway which makes the file completely useless. Our project is very large with a lot of js files so I don't know if that was the problem but when it was refreshing the intellisense it took ages and this seems to stop that happening.

Hope this helps someone! :)

Reference: http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs